# How to update dictionary in Swift located at every index of Array

Tags: dictionary, swift, ios8, xcode6.1

This response is coming from server in JSON format
posts =

```
(
            {
        commentCount = 0;
        "country_id" = 225;
        "country_name" = "United States";
        dislikeCount = 2;
        disliked = 0;
        firstname = Test;
        imageHeight = 0;
        imagePath = "";
        imageWidth = 0;
        lastname = Test;
        likeCount = 2;
        liked = 0;
        postid = 126;
        posttime = "2014-11-10 12:26:43";
        shareCount = 0;
        statusUpdate = Hello;
        "upload_type" = text;
        userId = 13;
        userimage = "https://Test.com/1409976093.png";
        videoHeight = "";
        videoPath = "";
        videoThumbnail = "";
        videoWidth = "";
    },
            {
        commentCount = 0;
        "country_id" = 225;
        "country_name" = "United States";
        dislikeCount = 2;
        disliked = 0;
        firstname = Test;
        imageHeight = 0;
        imagePath = "";
        imageWidth = 0;
        lastname = Test;
        likeCount = 3;
        liked = 0;
        postid = 125;
        posttime = "2014-10-28 17:50:00";
        shareCount = 0;
        statusUpdate = "Happy%20chhata%20puja%20to%20you%20and%20your%20family%0Athanks%0ADr%20shah%20family";
        "upload_type" = text;
        userId = 78;
        userimage = "https://Test.com/1410142960.png";
        videoHeight = "";
        videoPath = "";
        videoThumbnail = "";
        videoWidth = "";
    }
```

Now I need to update the value of "liked" from 0 to 1 locally but I am not able to do that. I have stored this array in my array like this:

```
self.homePageDataArray.addObjectsFromArray(dictionary["posts"] as NSMutableArray)
```

And I am able to fetch the content from every index and also able to show this in TableView but I want to changed the status of "liked" from 0 to 1 when user will tap on the "Like Button" in my app. Obviously I will update this on server but I want to update that locally as well parallely.
Please let me know how it can be achieved. I tried a lot but every time it is showing some error! For Instance,

```
var tempDic:Dictionary<AnyObject,AnyObject> = self.homePageDataArray[selectedRow] as Dictionary
```

I am getting this error

```
Type 'AnyObject' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'
```

Ultimately, I want to able to able to use the "updateValue" method so that I can update the value of my dictionary in my array.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
var tempDic = self.homePageDataArray[selectedRow] as Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

Your version:

```
var tempDic:Dictionary<AnyObject,AnyObject> = self.homePageDataArray[selectedRow] as Dictionary
```

Will not work because `AnyObject` is not conformable to `Hashable`, a requirement for the generic key type in `Dictionary`.

---

And to answer your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27105054/2747515):

```
var tempDic = self.homePageDataArray[selectedRow] as NSMutableDictionary as Dictionary
```

The statement above compiles because `Dictionary` is bridgeable to it's Objective-C counterpart; `NSMutableDictionary`. Your resultant dictionary will be of type `Dictionary<String, AnyObject>`. You're probably wondering how the type `String` was inferred. Well, `NSMutableDictionary` uses `NSString` as keys, a type which is bridgeable to it's Swift counterpart, you guessed it; `String`.

Answer (score 0):

**I really don't know WHY,** but following solution worked for me

```
var tempDic = self.homePageDataArray[selectedRow] as NSMutableDictionary as Dictionary
```

If anyone can explain then it will help others also!